# fluentd s3 output plugin configuration

Tags: amazon-s3, fluentd

I am trying to get the out_s3 for fluentd working from the past 2 days, I am unable to see the logs on my s3

This is my current config:

```
<match web.all>
        type s3
        aws_key_id ......
        as_sec_key ......
        s3_bucket ......
        path logs/
        buffer_path /var/log/td-agent/s3
        s3_region ap-southeast-1
        time_slice_format %Y%m%d%H%M
        time_slice_wait 1M
        utc

    buffer_chunk_limit 256m
</match>
```

If I try to match the 'web.all' and store it to a file, it works properly

```
<match web.all>
  type file
  path /var/log/td-agent/web-all.log
</match>
```

For some reason and not knowing how to debug, I am unable to put it on s3. Any direction on how to go about in debugging this?

**EDIT**

```
2015-10-18 22:46:51 -0400 [error]: unexpected error error_class=RuntimeError error=#<RuntimeError: can't call S3 API. Please check your aws_key_id / aws_sec_key or s3_region configuration. error = #<AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.>>
```

But the key provided is valid. I am able to see change in access key "last used time" update every time I restart td-agent.

Comment: Thanks for trying out Fluentd. Can you paste your Fluentd error logs? It should be in /var/log/td-agent/td-agent.log if you are using td-agent. If you are using Fluentd, then it should be wherever you specified to store logs.